# Modify function and keep code workability

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm not a professional coder, but I use Python time to time for my scientific needs. So I want to learn what is the most Pythonic way to do the following:

I'm working with an already existed module, and some class there looks like that

```py
class ATS(Instrument):

    def __init__(self, ..., dll_path: str):
        ... 
        self._dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
        ...

    def _call_dll(self, func_name: str, *args) -> None:
        func = getattr(self._dll, func_name)
        output = func(*args)
        ...
```

I found that I need to use different DLLs to call its own functions (unfortunately, the names of the functions in different DLLs can be the same).

The question is: What is the most Pythonic way to modify that `_call_dll` function to explicitly specify which DLL I want to use to call a particular function. In the same time, I want to keep workability of the rest of the code, where old version of `_call_dll` is used.

I see several ways to do this, but I'm not sure which one is most professional and good-styling.

1. Create its own `_call_dll_n` function for each `dll_n` I want to use, but it's not compact and nice.
2. Add some prefix to the function name to specify DLL, like

   ```py
   class ATS(Instrument):
       def __init__(self, ..., dll_path, dll_path_1, ...):
           ... 
           self._dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
           self._dll_1 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path_1)
           ...

       def _call_dll(self, pre_func_name: str,  *args) -> None:
           if prefix_func_name[:5] == 'dll_1':
               dll = self._dll_1
               func_name = pre_func_name[5:]
               func = getattr(dll, func_name)
            ...
            else:
                dll = self._dll  # Default DLL.
                func_name = pre_func_name
   ```
3. Make my_call_dll:

   ```py
   def _my_call_dll(self, func_name: str, dll = None, *args))
       if dll is None:
           self._call_dll(self, func_name, *args)      
       else:
           dll_bckp = self._dll
       self._dll = dll

       self._call_dll(self, func_name, *args)

       self._dll = dll_bckp
   ```

Your help on this particular example is appreciated, but also more general ideas about how to work and modify already existed functions/classes are very welcome.

Comment: Is the source code of the original module version controlled (e.g. is it form Github)?

Comment: Yes, it is from github, but I prefer to have my own version of the module (honestly, I'm just not sure that my modifications are made in a proper way to share it with somebody).

Comment: “I found that I need to use different dlls to call its own functions”; can you add another paragraph in the description, explaining what condition determines which DLL to use on a given occasion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the code; the ATS class, as you presented it, already allows for what you've described. Instead: **create multiple instances of ATS**, each one specifying which DLL to use.

Your description of the problem entails two parts:

- A [*mapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)#In_computer_science), from some key to the DLL file path.
- An [*API wrapper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library), allowing you to specify a key into the above mapping when you call the API.

In Python, the [built-in ‘dict’ type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is the natural way to implement a mapping. You can use a plain string as the key.

```py
import os.path


# You might get the path to your DLL files some other way,
# for example by reading a process environment variable.
# In this example I just hard-code the path root.
dll_file_path_root = os.path.join('/usr/lib', 'ats')

dll_file_paths = {
    'foo': os.path.join(dll_file_path_root, 'foo.dll'),
    'bar': os.path.join(dll_file_path_root, 'bar_v5.dll'),
    'baz': os.path.join(dll_file_path_root, 'super_baz.dll'),
}
```

The existing ATS class, as you present it above, already implements an API wrapper. Each instance will hold a reference (its internal-use `_dll` attribute) for which DLL that ATS instance will talk to. The class will initialise each instance of ATS with whatever DLL you specify. So:

```py
# Create an ATS instance that holds a reference to the ‘foo.dll’ library.
foo_ats = ATS(dll_path=dll_file_paths['foo'])
# Create an ATS instance that holds a reference to the ‘bar_v5.dll’ library.
bar_ats = ATS(dll_path=dll_file_paths['bar'])

# Call the ‘lorem’ function in the ‘foo.dll’ library.
foo_ats._call_dll(func_name='lorem')
# Call the ‘lorem’ function in the ‘bar_v5.dll’ library.
bar_ats._call_dll(func_name='lorem')
```

This is one of the primary benefits of defining classes: They encapsulate the common behaviour of a class of objects, while allowing each object to have individual attributes that differentiate them.